# Q: Nginx $upstream_response_time returns 2 values

Tags: nginx

Sometimes Nginx $upstream_response_time returns 2 values.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [08/Nov/2017:23:43:25 +0900] "GET /xxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/2.0" 200 284 "https://xxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" "-" "0.015" "0.001, 0.014"
```

"**0.001, 0.014**" this is a $upstream_response_time.
Why does this has two values?

Log format:

```
log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$request_time" "$upstream_response_time"';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this is spelled out in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables):

> Times of several responses are separated by commas and colons like addresses in the $upstream_addr variable.

This means that it made multiple requests to a backend, most likely you either have a bare `proxy_pass` host that resolves to different IPs (frequently the case with something like Amazon ELB as an origin), are you have a configured `upstream` that has multiple servers. Unless disabled, the `proxy` module will make round robin attempts against all healthy backends. This can be configured from [proxy_next_upstream_*](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream) directives.

For example if this is not the desired behavior, you can just do:

```
proxy_next_upstream off;
```

Comment: thank you!
with

proxy_next_upstream off;

it worked well as my expectation. returned single value.

Comment: And if disabled, how it will exactly choose the one from multiple backends?
Btw, the doc is not really correct, it tells 'Times of several connections are separated by commas and colons...', but in reality I see comma+space as the separator (or would space be 'colon' here?), which makes parsing the field from otherwise space-separated log files nasty.

Comment: If not disabled it is round robin